# what is wrong with my coding ? with java - swing

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm Tring to make the program. That click the button. Create drawings. and also click another button to make it move.

But I have a something wrong with the beginning.

1st. Eventhough I use super & actionlistener It compiles well but it doesn't work at all.

2nd. How should I code with afterwards with using Thread?
->(It doesn't mean that teach me whole code. I want some advice before I screw up everything.)

Here is my coding.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Hello extends JComponent{
//This is main code to create GUI
public Hello(){

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

public void run(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//set Frame & layout
JPanel south = new JPanel();
testpane center = new testpane();
JButton b1 = new JButton("Create");
b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
b1.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,20));
south.add(b1);
//setting the first button to create Things. i'll create another for move

b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //repaint(); -> this was my trial for not working
        center.setoutput();
    }

    //create action listener and **Here is the place I have a trouble**
});
frame.getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setTitle("Robot");
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
});
}
public class testpane extends JPanel{
testpane(){

}
public void setoutput(){
repaint();
}// this is the fuction to call repaint at Hello class
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.fillRect(100,100,30,30);
g2.drawRect(100, 100,30, 30);
g2.dispose();
}//this is the Thing that I want to draw
}
public static void main(String[] args){
new Hello();
}
//main class.
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear in what exactly it is that isn't working/you need to know?

Comment: ActionListener is not listening.. And I want to know the way to make the created object move.

Comment: something like when I clicked the button. The rectangle doesn't appaer at the frame

Comment: I think you've over-complicated things a bit. Try making `Hello`extend `JFrame`, don't use `frame.getContentPane().add` instead use `frame.add`. I also don't understand why you're using `Runnable`.

Comment: I'm trying to use runnable for make the object move... Is there a problem?

Comment: Read the section section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for a better example on how to structure your program. The `LabelDemo` source code is a good place to start for the basics of creating a Swing program. Also class name start with an upper case character.  @moarCoffee, `Try making Helloextend JFrame,` - don't extend JFrame. You only extend a class when you add new functionality to the class. Adding components is not adding functionality.

Comment: `make the object move... ` - define move. Do you want the object to move 1 pixel every time you click the button, or do you want to start animation so the object continues to move until you click on a stop button.

Comment: the latter one. start a animation so the object continues to move.

Comment: Well then read the link I gave you. In the table of contents you will find a section on `How to Use a Swing Timer`. When the Timer fires you move the rectangle. But that is the last step. You need to first restructure the code. You need to create a `move(...)` method for your custom painting so you can change the x/y location of the rectangle. That is you can't hard code 100/100.

Comment: Thanks for advice ^^, it helped alot

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a little bit your code to be more readable.
You simply never added the **center** JPanel to the frame

*Now the paint appears at once when you open the window you can modify it you know by if else or something or add the JPanel **center** at the JFrame when the button is clicked..*

Here is your code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Hello extends JFrame {

// This is main code to create GUI
public Hello() {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // set Frame & layout
            JPanel south = new JPanel();
            testpane center = new testpane();
            JButton b1 = new JButton("Create");
            b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 20));
            south.add(b1);
            // setting the first button to create Things. i'll create
            // another for move

            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // repaint(); -> this was my trial for not working
                    center.setoutput();
                }

                // create action listener and **Here is the place I have a
                // trouble**
            });


            getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            getContentPane().add(center,BorderLayout.CENTER); //Here you never have added the panel to the frame
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Robot");
            setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


///JPanel Class
public class testpane extends JPanel {  

    public void setoutput() {
        System.out.println("Entered setoutput");
        repaint();
    }

    //Paint Method
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Entered paint");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(100, 100, 30, 30);
        g2.drawRect(100, 100, 30, 30);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}




//Main Class
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Hello();
}



}//End of center class
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hmm. from this code. This is just create the rect already. But What I want is to create the rect when I click the button.

Comment: err now I got sth with buttons and get move. But how could I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

First of all add JPanel to your JFrame like this

```
frame.add(south);
```

When You call another class in main method use this method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Hello h = new Hello();
}
```

I have made changes in your code and now it is working

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Hello extends JFrame {

public Hello() {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel south = new JPanel();
            testpane center = new testpane();
            JButton b1 = new JButton("Create");
            b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 20));
            south.add(b1);

            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    center.setoutput();
                }

            });

            getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            getContentPane().add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("Robot");
            setSize(500, 500);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class testpane extends JPanel {

    public void setoutput() {
        System.out.println("Entered setoutput");
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Entered paint");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(100, 100, 30, 30);
        g2.drawRect(100, 100, 30, 30);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello h = new Hello();
 }

}
```